# Как делать плеер как вконтакте, который постоянно играет?

Tags: jquery, html

На сайте есть радио. Как можно сделать, чтобы при клике на кнопку play радио играло... и не переставало играть, пока юзер "бегает" по сайту, то есть открывает страницы и так далее.... чтобы плеер не гразулися с перезагрузкой страницы... подобная тема есть на сайте вконтакте...  у них плеер как-то отдельно открывается и его можно перетаскивать

Comment: На сайте ВКонтакте разве странички не javascript'ом подгружаются?

Comment: http://hashcode.ru/questions/16774/%D1%81%D1%82%D1%80%D0%BE%D1%87%D0%BA%D0%B0-%D0%BA%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%8F-%D0%B8%D0%B7%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%82-%D0%BC%D0%B8%D1%80

Comment: Нет, там через CSS.

Comment: uWeb, неужели?
До чего дошёл прогресс, <strike>у Серёжи ПМСу аякса CSS.

Comment: VK написан на nodeJS это совсем иная технлогия.

Answer (score 2):

Сам сайт реализован с помощью технологии Ajax, то есть переход по ссылке никак не влияет на сам плеер, так как сайт работает в асинхронном режиме.А плеер может свободно подгружаться из файла.

Comment: GenchiK вы немного не правы с помощью аякса не плеер подгружается, а страницы, запрос к страницам идет, а не к плееру 
Вот мой совет учите Ajax 
p.s я сам аякс не очень знаю но смысл структуры понимаю

Comment: А я что написал? П.С Во-первых я знаю Ajax, в отличие от Вас, во-вторых Вы далеки от того уровня, чтобы мне указывать что учить, а что читать.

Comment: Вообще то коментарии существуют. Ответ где более 70% обсуждается другой ответ - это глупо :D

Answer (score 0):

Сайт на аяксе (разработка, поддержка) стоит намного дороже, чем обычный сайт. Не стоит переписывать сайт на аяксе ради одной фичи. Лучше использовать айфрейм с контентом страниц, а плеер держать в теле главной страцицы. Хотя и в этом случае есть подводные камни: нужно решать проблему записи переходов в историю браузера, закидывать в адресную строку актуальный адрес страницы и т.д. Но готовые решения в виде плагинов к jQuery есть.

Comment: Как может быть дорого, если Дуров сам проггер?!Люди!Аякс это не такая тяжёлая технология, изучается за 6-7 часов полностью.Это даже не ЯП! Я тут многих сейчас удивил конечно на счёт ЯП, но не переживайте ;)

Comment: Эм, а для использования AJAX'а в каком-то месте нужно, оказывается, весь сайт переписывать?

Comment: @Construct - чтобы реализовать подобную фичу - да. Любой переход по любой ссылке должен быть реализован с помощью html5 history api. Соответственно переписывать надо многое. При условии что сайт написан грамотно это не так сложно, но если сайт написан как-нибудь - действительно переписывать нужно практически все